# git "Already up to date" even after removing local directory

Tags: git

I was modifying some files in a local copy of mythtv, but I wanted the original files back.

I was used to the subversion way: just delete the folder and checkout.

This does not work on git: it says it's already up to date. Doing a `git reset --hard HEAD` didn't work.

Comment: Doing `git reset --hard HEAD` should definitely work, unless you have committed your changes. `git checkout -f HEAD -- .` might also be worth a try

Comment: ^i concur that should definitely work.

Answer (score 1):

```
git reset --hard
```

should work. You may have committed the work. If you did, check with `git log`. If you see your commits in there, you can discard those with

```
git reset --hard HEAD~n
```

where n is however many commits you have.

If the files that are modified are things that are specified by the ignore file, you can get rid of those with

```
git clean -xdf
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
git reflog
```

to see your commit history. That should show you the history and you might recognize what you've done. Then, to revert back to a point in time where you know things are good, use:

```
git reset --hard <the reflog commit SHA>
```

Use [this](http://effectif.com/git/recovering-lost-git-commits) as a reference when working with the reflog.